# How to manage users from API on PHP

Tags: php, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Thanks for your help!! We have 2 more thing for need your Help.

1. how to generate when function making new users
2. please tell reference of UserStatusId

maybe 1001=active;
in portal, we can see active,disable,inactive and vpn only.
please tell us correct UserStatusId number.

Thanks in advance,
Naoki.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://forums.softlayer.com/forum/softlayer-developer-network/implementations/85004-how-to-manage-users-from-api-on-php

the statusID are:
1001 = Active; 1002 = Disable; 1003 = Inactive; 1021 = Delete ; 1022 = VPN Only

Regards